# How to capture action of hyperlinks of adaptive card in c#

Tags: c#, .net, botframework, adaptive-cards

I want to capture of action performed on hyperlink on Microsoft bot adaptive card. Using selection action I can capture the action but it's applicable for whole sentence. However, **I want it to capture if it's clicked on link only**. Below is my JSON template.

```
{
"type": "AdaptiveCard",
"body": [{
    "type": "Container",
    "items": [{
            "type": "ColumnSet",
            "columns": [{
                "type": "Column",
                "items": [{
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "size": "Medium",
                    "weight": "Bolder",
                    "text": "Test header",
                    "wrap": true
                }],
                "width": "stretch"
            }]
        },

        {
            "type": "ColumnSet",
            "columns": [{
                "type": "Column",
                "items": [{
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "weight": "Bolder",
                    "text": "- first test [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ)",
                    "wrap": true
                }],
                "width": "stretch",
                "selectAction": {
                    "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
                    "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ"
                }
            }]
        },
        {
            "type": "ColumnSet",
            "columns": [{
                "type": "Column",
                "items": [{
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "weight": "Bolder",
                    "text": "- second test [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ)",
                    "wrap": true
                }],
                "width": "stretch"
            }]
        },
        {
            "type": "ColumnSet",
            "columns": [{
                "type": "Column",
                "items": [{
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "weight": "Bolder",
                    "text": "- third test [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ)",
                    "wrap": true
                }],
                "width": "stretch"
            }]
        }

    ]
}],
"backgroundImage": {
    "url": "#",
    "fillMode": "RepeatVertically"
},
"$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
"version": "1.0",
"id": "test"
```

}

Can you please guide me how can I achieve it?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "capture action"? Are you talking about logging the action or otherwise performing some additional action when the user clicks a link? Also, what do you mean when you say "I want it to capture if it's clicked on link only"? Are you saying you want different behavior based on which part of the text block the user clicks on? Do you still want to open the link when the user clicks on any part of the text block or do you only want to open the link when the user clicks on one specific part? Does this sample help? https://github.com/EricDahlvang/OpenUrlRedirectBot

Comment: Thanks @KyleDelaney for this link. Yes I want to store some additional details of link and user in DB if user clicks on hyperlink. Yes I want to open link in new window if user clicks on hyperlink(specific part). 
Given url is using adaptive card version 1.2 but I want to achieve it using adaptive card version 1.0.

Comment: What channel/client are you using? It sounds like you're saying that "capture action" does mean logging the action. So when you said "Using selection action I can capture the action but it's applicable for whole sentence" does that mean you're already able to log the action? How are you doing that?

Comment: My bot is for web and teams channel. Yes I am using Action.Submit and therefore it's applying on whole sentence.

Comment: What do you mean you're using Action.Submit? There's no Action.Submit in your card. Can you please clarify what you're trying to do and why?

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: Yes... Still finding solution. In given example there is no Action.submit but I tried both. Action.submit and Action.openurl. using action.openurl I can open link but unable to send activity to bot and using Action.submit I can send activity to bot but unable to open link.

Comment: So why not use the redirect functionality from the link I shared?

Comment: Do you still need help?